# configuring Samsung Xpress C460w and connect it wirelessly to the router

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, samsung

I just bought Samsung Xpress printer C460w and I installed the Linux package driver from its website, but I can't connect my printer wirelessly to my router. In other word, I didn't find how to connect the printer wirelessly from a Linux machine.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add more detail

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by connecting the Samsung Xpress C460w by wire to the router then accessing printer's control panel and connecting its wireless to my network, after that, disconnecting the wire from the router.
That is it :).
To be able to print, Linux drivers package have to be installed on the computer.